# Reference data cache Usecase In WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have following usecase to implement in an WSO2 ESB.

During server startup , I need to execute a service which will load reference data from DB . This will be cached ,  An API is exposed to fetch this data from cache. Client make call to this API , ESB fetch this data from cache and respond back to client.

Question is , is there a possibility to execute the service / data retrieval logic during ESB startu ?

Comment: Try writing a Cron Task with count 1.

Comment: will try this workaround , thanks a lot